# MySQL database not selected. where did I miss it?

Tags: php, mysql, html

After searching through related questions, I still couldn't get this issue resolved. A "registration successful" page is supposed to pop up after a form is submitted but instead, "No database selected" message appears. where did I miss it. here are the codes.

connect.php

```
<?php
//connect.php
$server = 'localhost';
$username   = 'root';
$password   = '';
$database   = 'esiro';
$connection = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
    mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");

?>
```

signup.php

```
<?php
//signup.php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';

echo '<h3>Sign up</h3>';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{
    /*the form hasn't been posted yet, display it
      note that the action="" will cause the form to post to the same page it is on */
    echo 

    '<form role="form" method="post" action="" class="cover_form">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="labelfield" for="username">User Name:</label><br>
    <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control"/><br>

    <label class="labelfield" for="pwd">Password:</label><br>
    <input class="inputfield" type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="user_pass"><br>
    <label class="labelfield" for="pwd"> Confirm Password:</label><br>
    <input class="inputfield" type="password" name="user_pass_check" class="form-control" id="pwd"><br>

    <label class="labelfield" for="email">Email Address:</label><br>
    <input  class="inputfield"type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="user_email">
  </div><br>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Complete Registration"/><br>
</form>
';
}
else
{
    /* so, the form has been posted, we'll process the data in three steps:
        1.  Check the data
        2.  Let the user refill the wrong fields (if necessary)
        3.  Save the data 
    */
    $errors = array(); /* declare the array for later use */

    if(isset($_POST['user_name']))
    {
        //the user name exists
        if(!ctype_alnum($_POST['user_name']))
        {
            $errors[] = 'The username can only contain letters and digits.';
        }
        if(strlen($_POST['user_name']) > 30)
        {
            $errors[] = 'The username cannot be longer than 30 characters.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'The username field must not be empty.';
    }


    if(isset($_POST['user_pass']))
    {
        if($_POST['user_pass'] != $_POST['user_pass_check'])
        {
            $errors[] = 'The two passwords did not match.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'The password field cannot be empty.';
    }

    if(!empty($errors)) /*check for an empty array, if there are errors, they're in this array (note the ! operator)*/
    {
        echo 'Uh-oh.. a couple of fields are not filled in correctly...';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($errors as $key => $value) /* walk through the array so all the errors get displayed */
        {
            echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>'; /* this generates a nice error list */
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

         else
    {


        //the form has been posted without, so save it
        //notice the use of mysql_real_escape_string, keep everything safe!
        //also notice the sha1 function which hashes the password
        $sql = "INSERT INTO
                    users(user_name, user_pass, user_email ,user_date, user_level)
                VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "',
                       '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
                       '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "',
                        NOW(),
                        0)";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result)
        {
            //something went wrong, display the error
            echo 'Something went wrong while registering. Please try again later.';
            echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Successfully registered. You can now <a href="signin.php">sign in</a> and start posting! :-)';
        }
    }
}

include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: you are connecting using `mysqli` and querying using `mysql`

Comment: You are using `mysqli_*` in `connect.php` & `mysql_*` in `signup.php`.Try to maintain same in both places.

Comment: I have changed both to mysql. I got this afterwards:    "No database selected"

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Change the script

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

Instead of use this
---------------------     
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
```

And also remove `echo mysql_error();` 
and use this `echo mysql_error($connection);`

> Add this also in instead of mysql_real_escape_string

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO
                users(user_name, user_pass, user_email ,user_date, user_level)
            VALUES('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['user_name']) . "',
                   '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
                   '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['user_email']) . "',
                    NOW(),
                    0)";
```

Comment: after replacing $result = mysql_query($sql); with $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) , I got this error message:  Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mathforum\signup.php on line 97
Something went wrong while registering. Please try again later.